# requirejs module searching for a .json.js file instead of .json

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I ran into a problem where when I call my *mirage_smokes.json* file using the require.js module, the script searches for *mirage_smokes.json.js* to no avail. (Obviously, the .js extension is not supposed to be there)

```
function getData() {
    require(['../JSON/mirage_smokes.json'], function(data) {
        document.getElementById(testJSON).innerHTML = data.number;
    });
}
```

[image]

What could be causing the bug?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS defaults to javascript files and will automatically add the extension to the end of your filename. So, you must tell RequireJS that you are looking for a JSON file by using this syntax:

```
require(['json!yourfile.json'], function(data) {
     ...
})
```

Alternatively, since RequireJS adds the extension to the end of the filename for you, you can leave off the .json extension if you wish:

```
require(['json!yourfile'], function(data) {
     ...
})
```

Comment: But! You need a RequireJS plugin for that: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins